# Simplify the expression $(2x^2 - 2)/(x+1)$ to 2x + 2

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I want to Simplify the expression $(2x^2 - 2)/(x+1)$. I've used wolfram alpha and even looked up the answer witch is 2x + 2. But I totaly forgot how! (I know it's pretty simple I have just forgott... thanks to all the smart people out there!

Comment: Can you factor $2x^2-2$?

Comment: Write $2x^2-2=2(x^2-1)=2(x-1)(x+1)$, and then cancel.

Comment: Ohh! Ofc! thank you guys!

Comment: am I missing something or does this actually simplify to 2x-2 not 2x+2

Answer (score 1):

$(2x^2-2)$ = $2(x^2-1)$= $2(x+1)(x-1)$

So the expression reduces to $2(x-1)$= $(2x-2)$

Are you sure the answer is $(2x+2)$